# Why the error is displayed as java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: for the following groovy code?

Tags: eclipse, groovy

```
class First {

    public First() {
        super()
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }
    static void main(String s)
    {
        print('Hii');
    }
}
```

After running the code in eclipse using Groovy Console option the following exception is being shown.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.ui.Console
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:179)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:151)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the code. Groovy Console dependencies are not included by default with Groovy 2.5+ You can use Groovy 2.4 which bundles groovy-all or run as Java Application since you have a class with a main method.